# Реализации регистрации и логина на сервере

Tags: php, android, json, сервер

Я пишу приложение для Android, мессенджер.
Делаю я этого исключительно для дипломной работы, в продакшн выпускать не буду.
Поэтому не реализую шифрование и вообще не продумываю безопасность.

В данный момент я реализовал все нужные мне функции, регистрация, логин, добавление друга, переписка. Но реализовал это все с локальной базой.
То есть когда человек нажимает регистрация, он создает новую запись логин-пароль в базе SQLite на устройстве. Так-же с логином и перепиской, хранится на устройстве.

Мне нужно реализовать регистрацию и логин на сервере.
То есть когда пользователь нажимает "регистрация", на сервере с MySQL запрашивается строка с login и password. Если такой уже есть то передать отказ на устройство, если нету то добавляем эти login и password.

Реализация Login, похожая схема. Если логин и пароль есть в MySQL то передаем что залогинился. Если нет то передаем отказ.

Собственно вопрос как сделать такую регистрацию и авторизацию на сервере?
Есть идея сделать на php API. И через JSON отправлять запрос на сервер.
Но как получать feedback? То есть как получать ответ от сервера на устройстве?

Может у вас есть более простые и легкие реализации данного функционала.
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Гуглите android http request. Пример больше чем полно

Comment: вы не знаете, как сделать запрос в интернет?

Answer (score 1):

Если сервер у вас реализован у вас на PHP, используйте например библиотеку [OkHttp](https://github.com/square/okhttp), с помощью которой, указав URL вашего запроса, вы получите ответ, например в виде того же JSON, и уже на стороне приложения разбирайтесь. (Хорошие примеры есть в этой бибилиотеке)